# Извлечение каталога из deb пакета через pipe

Tags: debian, shell

Необходимо извлечь из deb пакета некий каталог, например `/usr/share`, сделать это необходимо через pipe, то есть как-то так `wget -qO - http://.../package.deb | ar x data.tar.xz ...`
Смотрел разные команды и их опции, но так и не вышло решить эту задачу именно через pipe, без сохранения файлов на диск.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

программа *ar*, к сожалению, так не умеет. порылся в интернетах, не нашёл ничего подходящего. хотя [формат архива](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ar_(Unix)#File_format_details) довольно примитивен. потому набросал реализацию на *perl*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# arpipe - extract to stdout file data.tar.xz from ar passed to stdin

use autodie;
open my $fh, '<-:raw';
my $member = shift;

# read from $fh count bytes
sub read_from {
  my $count = shift;
  my $bytes_read = read $fh, my $bytes, $count;
  die "got $bytes_read but expected $count" unless $bytes_read == $count;
  return $bytes;
}

# parse member header
sub parse_header {
  my $header = shift;
  my ($name, $timestamp, $oid, $gid, $filemode, $size, $ending) =
    unpack 'A16 A12 A6 A6 A8 A10 a2', $header;
  die "expected end of header" unless $ending eq "\x60\x0a";
  return ($name, $size);
}

# read and check archive header
my $header0 = read_from(8);
die "expected header" unless $header0 eq "!<arch>\x0a";

# loop through members of archive
while(1) {
  my $header = read_from(60);
  ($name, $size) = parse_header($header);
  last if $name eq $member;
  read_from($size);
}

print read_from($size);
```

недостатки:

- в описании говорится о выравнивании на границу чётного байта, но я таких архивов не встретил, потому обработки нет.

использовать примерно так:

```
$ cat файл.deb | ./arpipe data.tar.xz | tar -tJ
```